# Debug with Zend Studio and Wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver, zend-studio

Recently I rebuilt my laptop running Windows 7 64-bit.  Before the rebuild I was running my own individual WAMP stack having installed all the components separately but after the rebuild I decided to try out a pre-built WAMP stack as it allowed me to easily switch between versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL so I settled on Wampserver.

However since I switched I cannot debug with Zend Studio.  I have the Zend debug bar installed in Firefox and normally I just set a break point in Zend Studio and within Firefox select a debug option i.e. debug this page, all pages, posts etc.  However this now doesn't trigger Zend Studio to enter debug mode and just bypasses everything.

I've added the following to my php.ini file as loaded by Apache (as seen from phpinfo):

```
[Zend]
zend_extension_ts="C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendDebugger/5_3_x_nts_comp/ZendDebugger.dll"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32,192.168.1.64,192.168.1/150
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

Also, Wampserver installed Xdebug and I commented out the following lines in php.ini incase there was any conflict:

```
; XDEBUG Extension

;zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"

;[xdebug]
;xdebug.remote_enable = off
;xdebug.profiler_enable = off
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

Would appreciate any advice or pointers in the right direction anyone can give me.

Thanks in advance.

PS. Am running PHP5.3

Comment: if you can't fix it, switch to eclipse and easyphp(which has Xdebug)

Comment: check phpinfo() if xdebug is disabled, maybe wrong php.ini?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Def using right version of php.ini as shown in phpinfo. Does it matter if using Zend Debugger if Xdebug is disabled or not?

Comment: I have this problem too if solve please share

Answer (score 0):

Switched to Netbeans and using XDebug.  Great IDE with very usable debugging.